# Strip last part of file by pattern - remove last certificate from chain

Tags: awk, sed, ack

I have a chain of SSL certificates like this

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIICPjCCAeSgAwIBAgIRALMMpKnhRM2C7mnKI/rl8ggwCgYIKoZIzj0EAwIwgY4x
CERT1
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIDIjCCAsegAwIBAgIOAMjnPM1wShDmOWUELuIwCgYIKoZIzj0EAwIwgagxCzAJ
CERT2
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIDIDCCAsWgAwIBAgIOAMjnPL8JUbVSmpMadWUwCgYIKoZIzj0EAwIwbDELMAkG
CERT3
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIDBjCCAqygAwIBAgIFFRCCEwYwCgYIKoZIzj0EAwIwgZQxFDASBgNVBAoMC0Ft
CERT4
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIDNjCCAtugAwIBAgIJAKpBxYNyH8biMAoGCCqGSM49BAMCMIGUMRQwEgYDVQQK
CERT5
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

and I need to strip the last certificate from it.

On MacOS/BSD command `split` has flag `-p` to split by pattern, and I used it:

```
cat cert | split -p "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----" 
cat xa{a,b,c,d}
```

I believe there is a command to do it in one line on Linux too, but on Ubuntu the command `split` is not able to split by pattern.

I need to do the job using standard linux commands, such as those I tagged.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This GNU Sed solution should be enough:

```bash
sed -zE 's/(.*\n)-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----.*/\1/' your_input
```

- `-E` allows one to use `(…)` instead of `\(…\)` to capture something;
- `-z` (available in GNU Sed) is to treat the whole input as a single long string with embedded `\n`s.

Therefore, the first `.*` matches as much as it can (and captures it, together with the `\n` right after it, so it can reference it in the substitution by using `\1`), as long as it is followed by `\n-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` and anything else after it (the second `.*`).

Comment: it removes last `-----END CERTIFICATE-----` but sure it works. Thank you.

Comment: @kyb, don't you want to remove it? Please, include the desired output in your question, then.

Comment: This command outputs 4 certs, stripping the 5th. That's what i am looking for. But the 4th cert looks broken because it does not have *-----END CERTIFICATE-----*. I'd like to see 4 valid cert in output. (Of course it is easy to add it manually with `echo`)

Comment: @kyb I have fixed it (upon Ed's suggestion, honestly). Basically I had `(.*)\n` which was not capturing, thus deleting, the last newline at the EOF, which is required by some VS editors (VS = very stupid); changing that to `(.*\n)` keeps the last newline in the captured group and therefore in the output, thus making those editors happy.

Comment: yes. now it works as expected. thank you. I did not know about `-z` before.

Comment: I do not use VS editor. In my input certs chain there is no last empty line. And therefore it did not work.

Answer (score 3):

With any awk alone:

```
$ awk '/-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----/{printf "%s", rec; rec=""} {rec=rec $0 ORS}' file
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIICPjCCAeSgAwIBAgIRALMMpKnhRM2C7mnKI/rl8ggwCgYIKoZIzj0EAwIwgY4x
CERT1
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIDIjCCAsegAwIBAgIOAMjnPM1wShDmOWUELuIwCgYIKoZIzj0EAwIwgagxCzAJ
CERT2
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIDIDCCAsWgAwIBAgIOAMjnPL8JUbVSmpMadWUwCgYIKoZIzj0EAwIwbDELMAkG
CERT3
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIDBjCCAqygAwIBAgIFFRCCEwYwCgYIKoZIzj0EAwIwgZQxFDASBgNVBAoMC0Ft
CERT4
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

or if you have `tac`:

```
$ tac file | awk 'f; /-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----/{f=1}' | tac
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIICPjCCAeSgAwIBAgIRALMMpKnhRM2C7mnKI/rl8ggwCgYIKoZIzj0EAwIwgY4x
CERT1
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIDIjCCAsegAwIBAgIOAMjnPM1wShDmOWUELuIwCgYIKoZIzj0EAwIwgagxCzAJ
CERT2
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIDIDCCAsWgAwIBAgIOAMjnPL8JUbVSmpMadWUwCgYIKoZIzj0EAwIwbDELMAkG
CERT3
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIDBjCCAqygAwIBAgIFFRCCEwYwCgYIKoZIzj0EAwIwgZQxFDASBgNVBAoMC0Ft
CERT4
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Comment: Have you any idea what the OP complains about with this output? (See their comment under my question.)

Comment: @Enrico I suspect they're using an editor or some other tool to verify the output that was discarding/hiding the last line of your output because it didn't end in a newline (I know you fixed that now) so to them that final END line was missing.

Comment: Oooooow, I thought that they were referring to the original last line! They were obviously referring to the error you corrected in my code. Thanks again, then.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm just guessing that that's what it was about of course but it seems likely and I can't think of anything else!

Answer (score 3):

With GNU `awk` using `gensub` you could try following, written and tested based on shown samples only.

```
awk -v RS="" -v regex="(.*)\n(-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----.*)" '
{
  print gensub(regex,"\\1","1",$0)
}' Input_file
```

Comment: As far as I understand RS="" is for "slurp mode" so $0 contains full input file. Right?

Comment: @kyb no, `RS=""` (or `RS=''`) is for "paragraph mode"` where records are separated by blank lines. `RS='^$'` (if your awk version supports multi-char RS) is for "slurp mode" where $0 contains the full input file. They behave similarly when the input doesn't contain any blank lines (which is probably your situation) except that with `RS=""`$0 will not contain the last newline in the file while with `RS='\0'` it will. To see the difference try `echo 7 | awk -v RS='' '{print "<" $0 ">"}'` and `echo 7 | awk -v RS='^$' '{print "<" $0 ">"}'` and note the newline before `>` in the first output.

Comment: @EdMorton, Thank you sir for clarifying here sorry my understanding was wrong.